# What is this and how do I delete it?

Tags: macos, ln

This is on my MacOS shell. I can't delete X11R6@ and I don't know what it is. Help?

[image]

Comment: if you do not know what it is, then why are you deleting it? ... anyway, it is just a link

Answer (score 3):

> What is this

It's a soft link.

It points to /opt/X11 where some X11 stuff is apparently installed.

> how do I delete it?

You can always delete it with a `rm X11R6` command -- if you have root privileges, or if you are logged in as user `pitosalas`. Although, I don't see why you would bother deleting it, and possibly breaking something that needs to find the X11 stuff.

Comment: The OP might be missing the fact that the `@` symbol is not an actual part of the file name - it is just an indicator that the file is a symbolic link. Those indicator characters appear only if the option `-F` is in effect for the `ls` command - there might be a default shell alias or function that adds that option to plain `ls`. The current aliases can usually be viewed by using the `alias`command without parameters.

Comment: I thought normally the arrow alone denotes symlink and the at sign meant something more...or else...